# Prevent Outlook 2007 from reformatting phone numbers?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, contacts, phone

I'm using the US version of Outlook 2007 in Europe, so would like Outlook to save phone numbers as-is instead of reformatting them US-style:

[image]

I checked the Phones + Modem application in XP's Control Panel, to no avail. No option either in Outlook's Tools > Options.

Does someone know if there's a way to tell Outlook to stop formatting phone numbers?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Provided you don't have a modem in the computer, the solution is to disable Windows' Telephony service, that Outlook uses to reformat phone numbers based on the user's location. After disabling that service, Outlook will let users type whatever they want as phone numbers. More infos here : http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=683480&#r19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem ([thread 1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/exchangesvrclients/thread/27361a48-5c74-4554-b589-7e28723298d1), [thread 2](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/683480)). Apparently, there is no option in Outlook or Windows to disable this feature.

To stop Outlook from automatically changing the layout of the phone numbers you will need to change your phone area code to be more than 5 digits.

Keep in mind that this might break other features, like VOIP dialing or connecting to the Internet through a dial up connection.

**Doing this (as inelegant as it is) should work:**

1. Click the Start button, and select Control Panel.
2. Under the list, select Phone and Modem Options.
3. Click on the Edit button.
4. Change the Area code to 99999.
5. Click OK and OK to save the settings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It requires editing all the existing items in Contacts, but it's good enough.